# Website doesn't reflect Stripe customer/subscription changes

Tags: laravel, database, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I have a website built with the Laravel framework that uses Stripe to process subscription payments. When a user subscribes to a plan *through my website*, this row appears in the "subscriptions" database table:

[image]

When a subscription is canceled *through my website*, the `ends_at` column is populated with a date the current subscription period ends and will not be renewed:

[image]

This is the desired behavior, however, when a payment method is invalid, Stripe automatically cancels the subscription *outside of the website*. Since the subscription was canceled automatically on Stripe's end, my website doesn't reflect the changes and the `ends_at` database column will indefinitely have a value of `NULL`, allowing the user to continue using premium features of the website for free.

This is how I currently check if a user has an active subscription plan on my website:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if (!$user->subscribed('plan') && $user->posts->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
            $post->update(['status' => 'unpublished']);
        }
    }

    return view('dashboard');
}
```

This is how a user cancels their subscription on my website:

```
public function cancel()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->subscription('plan')->cancel();

    return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Subscription canceled.");
}
```

How do I fix this issue so my website will automatically check Stripe for a customer's subscription status?

Comment: that's why you can configure your webhooks for requests from stripe to your server when changes happens (renew subscription/ cancel subscription) https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks you can secure those webhook with IP verification, there is a list of stripe servers IPs in the docs (sandbox and live)